# Change Editing Style for UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios

Going through the BigNerdRanch's guide to iOS and one of the tasks is to add a "No More Items" cell to the bottom of a list of items in a UITableView. So, I added the item to the bottom, but I want to make it so that I cannot delete it and I cannot reorder it.

I can set the reordering by doing: canMoveRowAtIndexSource to NO. However, the delete button still appears. I know I can reject a delete confirmation for the rows that I don't want removed, but I don't want the delete buttons to appear at all.

I know I can get rid of the delete button by setting canEditRowAtIndexPath to NO. However, when i go into edit mode, those rows look wonky because they're no longer indented.

It looks like I can indent the content of a cell, but not a cell itself. Is that right?

What would be the best approach to this problem? Even the name of a method would be really helpful.

Comment: If you centre the text of the bottom cell and make it appear visually different to the cells that contain something, it won't look wonky.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was use the editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath and check there if cell were deletable, like this:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if(... can delete ...)
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```